# I can't seem to add a column header to a list box in an inherited MFC dialog. What's wrong?

Tags: mfc, listbox, cdialog

I have a CStdDlg thats inherits from a CDialog class. In the CStdDlg dialog, I have a list box (m_lcList1), edit box (m_ceEdit1), a radio button(m_rbButton2) and buttons OK, Cancel and Button1.

I am trying to create another class named CDerivedDlg that inherits from CStdDlg. I want to use everything in CStdDlg but from the CDerivedDlg.
This is a silly test application here, but I need something exactly like this is a real application.

I'll show all the code below.  PROBLEM: The problem keeps bombing whenever I try to add a column header to the list box.   m_hWnd = NULL

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?  I would truly appreciate it.  Thank you.

```
// CStdDlg.cpp file

#include "stdafx.h"  
#include "testdlg.h"
#include "StdDlg.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#undef THIS_FILE
static char THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__;
#endif

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CStdDlg dialog
CStdDlg::CStdDlg(UINT nIDTemplate, CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(CStdDlg::IDD, pParent)
{
    //{{AFX_DATA_INIT(CStdDlg)
    //}}AFX_DATA_INIT
}
void CStdDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    //{{AFX_DATA_MAP(CStdDlg)
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT1, m_ceEdit1);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_RADIO2, m_rbButton2);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_LIST1, m_lcList1);
    //}}AFX_DATA_MAP
}
IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CStdDlg, CDialog)
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CStdDlg, CDialog)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CStdDlg)
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CStdDlg message handlers
BOOL CStdDlg::OnInitDialog() 
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
                  // EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE
}
===================================================================================

//CStdDlg.h file

#if !defined(AFX_STDDLG_H__CDAFF61F_91AB_4B47_9970_6B8BB5DE0003__INCLUDED_)
#define AFX_STDDLG_H__CDAFF61F_91AB_4B47_9970_6B8BB5DE0003__INCLUDED_

#if _MSC_VER > 1000
#pragma once
#endif // _MSC_VER > 1000
// StdDlg.h : header file
//
#include <afxwin.h>

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CStdDlg dialog

class CStdDlg : public CDialog
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CStdDlg)
// Construction
public:

    CStdDlg(UINT nIDTemplate,CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor
    CString GetTitle() { 
        CString csTTL;
        GetWindowText(csTTL);
        return csTTL;
    }
// Dialog Data
    //{{AFX_DATA(CStdDlg)
    enum { IDD = IDD_STDDLG };
    CEdit   m_ceEdit1;
    CButton m_rbButton2;
    CListCtrl   m_lcList1;
    //}}AFX_DATA


// Overrides
    // ClassWizard generated virtual function overrides
    //{{AFX_VIRTUAL(CStdDlg)
    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support
    //}}AFX_VIRTUAL

// Implementation
protected:
    void ShowMsg() { AfxMessageBox("ShowMsg from StdDlg"); }
    // Generated message map functions
    //{{AFX_MSG(CStdDlg)
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    //}}AFX_MSG
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

//{{AFX_INSERT_LOCATION}}
// Microsoft Visual C++ will insert additional declarations immediately before the previous line.

#endif // !defined(AFX_STDDLG_H__CDAFF61F_91AB_4B47_9970_6B8BB5DE0003__INCLUDED_)

===================================================================================
//CDerivedDlg.cpp file

// StdDlg.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "testdlg.h"
#include "CDerivedDlg.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#undef THIS_FILE
static char THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__;
#endif

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CDerivedDlg dialog


CDerivedDlg::CDerivedDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CStdDlg(CDerivedDlg::IDD, pParent)
{
    //{{AFX_DATA_INIT(CDerivedDlg)
    //}}AFX_DATA_INIT
}


void CDerivedDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    //{{AFX_DATA_MAP(CDerivedDlg)
    //}}AFX_DATA_MAP
}


IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CDerivedDlg, CStdDlg)
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CDerivedDlg, CStdDlg)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CDerivedDlg)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON1, OnButton1)
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CDerivedDlg message handlers


//void CDerivedDlg::OnOK() 
//{
//  // TODO: Add extra validation here
//  AfxMessageBox("CDerived Class OK button pressed");
//  CDialog::OnOK();
//}

BOOL CDerivedDlg::OnInitDialog() 
{
    CStdDlg::OnInitDialog();
    SetWindowText("Derived Test Window");
    m_lcList1.InsertColumn(0,"This is a test");    *******THIS IS WHERE IT CRASHES*****


    m_rbButton2.ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
    m_ceEdit1.ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);



    return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
                  // EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE
}


void CDerivedDlg::OnButton1() 
{
//  // TODO: Add extra validation here
    AfxMessageBox("CDerived Button1 pressed");
    AfxMessageBox(GetTitle());

}

void CDerivedDlg::OnOK() 
{
    AfxMessageBox("CDerived Class OK button pressed");

}
===================================================================================
// CDerivedDlg.h file

#if !defined(AFX_CDerivedDlg_H__CDAFF61F_91AB_4B47_9970_6B8BB5DE0003__INCLUDED_)
#define AFX_CDerivedDlg_H__CDAFF61F_91AB_4B47_9970_6B8BB5DE0003__INCLUDED_

#if _MSC_VER > 1000
#pragma once
#endif // _MSC_VER > 1000
// CDerivedDlg.h : header file
//
#include "StdDlg.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CDerivedDlg dialog

class CDerivedDlg : public CStdDlg
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CDerivedDlg)
// Construction
public:
    CDerivedDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor
    virtual void SetTTL(CString csTitle) { this->SetWindowText(csTitle); }

// Dialog Data
    //{{AFX_DATA(CDerivedDlg)
    enum { IDD = IDD_STDDLG };
    //}}AFX_DATA


// Overrides
    // ClassWizard generated virtual function overrides
    //{{AFX_VIRTUAL(CDerivedDlg)
    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support
    //}}AFX_VIRTUAL

// Implementation
protected:

    // Generated message map functions
    //{{AFX_MSG(CDerivedDlg)
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    afx_msg void OnButton1();
    virtual void OnOK();
    //}}AFX_MSG
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

//{{AFX_INSERT_LOCATION}}
// Microsoft Visual C++ will insert additional declarations immediately before the previous line.

#endif // !defined(AFX_CDerivedDlg_H__CDAFF61F_91AB_4B47_9970_6B8BB5DE0003__INCLUDED_)
===================================================================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that since the DDX_Control() are on the base class, the derived class will not link the resource controls to their respective classes. You might want to try to change this:

```
void CDerivedDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
```

into this:

```
void CDerivedDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CStdDlg::DoDataExchange(pDX);
```

Comment: I gave this a try and it didn't make a difference.  What do you think of Nick's answer show above?
Thanks,
Mike

Comment: I thought I tried this, but when doing it again, the program now works!!!  Thank you very much.

Comment: You are correct.  It now works.  I must have done something before when I tried it. Thanks.  I hope you have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

```
m_lcList1.InsertColumn(0,"This is a test");    *******THIS IS WHERE IT CRASHES*****
```

You have to *create* the control before you'll be able to use it.
See [CListCtrl::Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2xhkzyh4%28VS.80%29.aspx) and/or [CListCtrl::CreateEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyyed8e0%28VS.80%29.aspx) methods.
You must choose the `LVS_REPORT` style since you want to use the list as a report view control.

Comment: Thanks.  Why would I have to create it?  If I was just using the CStdDlg without the CDerivedDlg class, I shouldn't have to create it.  I created another short mfc app with a list box and put the same type of code in the OnInitDialog function and it worked fine.  I did change the line to m_lcList.InsertColumn(0,"This is a test",LVCFMT_LEFT,200) but that only made the header appear.

Thanks again,
Mike

Comment: If you include the dialog templates in your applications, then yes, you don't have to explicitly create it. If you remove that problematic line, does your dialog box executes properly? Do you see the list as a blank window?

Comment: I include the dialog templates in the app. If I remove the problematic line, it works fine.  The list box is shown as a blank window except the first line is shown as light brown.

Comment: I am using VS 6.  I know it's older than the hills. :)

Comment: Are the IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC and DECLARE_DYNAMIC lines correct in both .cpp files?

Comment: In my VC++ 6.0 the wizard doesn't add IMPLEMENT/DECLARE_DYNAMIC macros. I don't think they are a problem, but try to disable/remove them. Did you implement the CDerivedDlg manually or with the wizard?

Comment: The problem was found.  I tried this before but it didn't work. I just tried it again and now it works!!  THe CDialog below needed to change to CStdDlg.  Thanks for all your help...Mike

    void CDerivedDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX){
       CStdDlg::DoDataExchange(pDX);

Comment: @Mike S, you can accept his answer by selecting the *check* mark. It's on the left side of the answer.